How to combine the counts from two PCollection into one Object
I have an apache beam pipeline that reads a CSV file and also makes a query to a bigquery table, I need to count how many registers are in each PCollection and based on that create a FinalResult object that has both counts, have not been able to figure out how to combine both result into one object.
Here is my code:


public Pipeline build() {


        PCollection<QueryData> queryData = pipeline.apply("Read from BigQuery",
                BigQueryIO.read(reader).fromQuery(reader.getQueryString()).usingStandardSql().withoutValidation());

        PCollection<Incident> incidentes = pipeline.apply("READ CSV", TextIO.read().from("gs://bucket/incidents.csv"))
                .apply("Convert to bean", ParDo.of(new IncidentCsvToBeanFunction()));

        PCollection<Long> queryDataCount = queryData.apply("Count QueryData", Count.globally());
        PCollection<Long> incidentesCount = incidentes.apply("Count Incidentes", Count.globally());

        // Missing how to combine both counts into FinalResult object, which im going to save later into another bigquery table

        return pipeline;
}

I am missing how to combine queryDataCount and incidentesCount into my FinalResult object which looks like:

public class FinalResult implements Serializable {

    private Integer numberOfIncidents;
    private Integer numberOfQueryData;

    // getters setters
}


This can be achieved by using side inputs.You can read the csv file using side input and query to bigquery table in pipeline and then pass the side input to the pipeline in the withSideInput method of the ParDo .
In your DoFn class retrieve it from the context using ProcessContext.sideInput() method and theere you can combine both the result to get desired result.
you can refer this https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/
Using side inputs with tags (or how to use ProcessContext.sideInput() correctly)
